# Interaction Summaries component - "New" button is not visible

Tags: page-layout, standard-objects, component, new, interaction

We have set up Interaction Summaries according to the Salesforce documentation and placed the "Interaction Summaries" component on the Account record page.
After deployment on the target org, we cannot see the "New" button on the Interaction Summaries component. On the DEV org all is working well.
[image]

I checked the following:

- Interaction Summary Settings is the same on both orgs
- Interaction and Interaction Summary permissions are set the same for both orgs
- User can create Interaction and Interaction summary from the object tabs but even when Interaction is related to the Account it is not visible on the component.
- Actions for Interaction and Interaction Summary are OOB ones and are the same.
- I even checked layouts for Interaction objects and they are the same as well including visible actions and buttons.

Is there any special permission required to show the "New" button here?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

**The solution to this problem was missing "Related To" (API Name: "whatId") edit permission to the Event object.**

Very surprising that Interaction Summary is related with Event object in the backend...